# how to get last added record for a battery with left join PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have query such as

```
select * from batteries as b ORDER BY inserted_at desc
```

which gives me data such as

[image]

and I have an query such as

```
select voltage, datetime, battery_id from battery_readings ORDER BY inserted_at desc limit 1
```

which returns data as

[image]

I want to combine both 2 above queries, so in one go, I can have each battery details as well as its last added voltage and datetime from battery_readings.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a very useful syntax for this, called `DISTINCT ON`.  This is different from plain DISTINCT in that it keeps only the first row of each set, defined by the sort order.  In your case, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.id)
  b.id,
  b.name,
  b.source_url,
  b.active,
  b.user_id,
  b.inserted_at,
  b.updated_at,
  v.voltage,
  v.datetime
FROM battery b
JOIN battery_voltage v ON (b.id = v.battery_id)
ORDER BY b.id, v.datetime desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that widowing will make what you expected.

Assuming two tables

```
create table battery (id int, name text);
create table bat_volt(measure_time int, battery_id int, val int);
```

One of the possible queries is like this:

```
with latest as (select battery_id, max(measure_time) over (partition by battery_id) from bat_volt)
  select * from battery b join bat_volt bv on bv.battery_id=b.id where (b.id,bv.measure_time) in (select * from latest);
```

If you have Postgres version which supports lateral, it might also make sense to try it out (in case there are way more values than batteries, it could have better performance).

```
select * from battery b 
  join bat_volt bv on bv.battery_id=b.id   
  join lateral 
  (select  battery_id, max(measure_time) over (partition by battery_id) from bat_volt bbv 
    where bbv.battery_id = b.id limit 1) lbb on (lbb.max = bv.measure_time AND lbb.battery_id = b.id);
```